# Calculating duplicate with dates in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, rank, excel-365

I have a project where I need to count the number of times that a movie was played, categorizing if it was the first, second, third... time according to its date.

I was able to count the occurrences per movie and to order them using `IF` and  `COUNTIF`. However, I can't come up with a formula that uses the date as well.

Also, I have to check for errors, because if the movie passes in a consecutive date, it needs to be counted just as one exibition.

[image: rank]

Comment: COUNTIFS() would be where I would start. Show what you have done, then we can work from there.

Comment: So, in the column occurrence I have the formula: =+COUNTIF([Description];[@Description]) and in the column Pase, I have =+IF(B2=B2;COUNTIF($B$2:B2;[@Description]);"").

Comment: Do you have Excel 365 and thus access to functions like `FILTER` and `SORT`?

Comment: Yes, but I want to solve this in a automatic way, not needing to filter everytime

Comment: Thanks. Could you also please clarify what you mean by: "if the movie passes in a consecutive date, it need to be counted just as one exibition". E.g. In your table `Twilight` has `22/06/2022` in row 1 and then `23/06/2022`. You want both of these entries then to count as `1`, correct?

Comment: HI ouroboros1, correct! Because the system cut the movie and make it appear as 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** we have a list of movies in a column "Description". Next to it is a column "Date", that references the date on which a particular movie was played. This column is **not** in chronological order. The goal is to create another column, let us call it "Desired_Rank", that ranks each play date in chronological order per movie. However, there's a catch: *consecutive play dates per movie need to be counted as one play date*. It is not allowed to re-order the rows first (which would make the problem much less difficult to solve).

Let's take a simplified example. Below is a table that contains movies A, B and C with a bunch of dates (some of them consecutive; all unique per movie). N.B. The dates here are sorted. This is just to help see the logic.

[image: desired result]

A regular rank for this would be simple enough. We could use:

```
=MATCH([@Date],SORT(FILTER([Date],[Description]=[@Description]),,1),0)
```

IIUC, we are looking for the "Desired_Rank", which groups together consecutive play dates (items within the black borders).

**Solution:** the mentioned constraint complicates the matter, but I've come up with the following formula to solve this one, and produce the outcomes in column "Desired_Rank":

```
=LET(movie,[@Description],date,[@Date],sorted,SORT(FILTER([Date],[Description]=movie),,1),match_date,MATCH(date,sorted,0),f_diff,IFERROR(INDEX(sorted,SEQUENCE(ROWS(sorted),,2))-sorted,0),sum_dupl,IFERROR(SUM(--(INDEX(f_diff,SEQUENCE(match_date-1))=1)),0),match_date-sum_dupl)
```

Here's the same data from above, but now randomly ordered. Still works as desired:

[image: desired result unsorted]

Let me explain what the formula actually does. The [`LET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999#:%7E:text=The%20LET%20function%20assigns%20names,through%20Excel%27s%20native%20formula%20syntax.) wrapper is used here to assign names to intermediate calculation results. This improves readability. Let's go over all the variables in order:

- `movie,[@Description]`: 1st, 2nd etc. movie.
- `date,[@Date]`: 1st, 2nd etc. date.
- `sorted,SORT(FILTER([Date],[Description]=movie),,1)`: here, [`FILTER`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) is used to get an array with dates per movie. [`SORT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c) with param `1` (= ascending) sorts this array in ascending order. I.e. for movie "A" we get `{44713;44714;44716;44718;44719}`.
- `match_date,MATCH(date,sorted,0)`: we use [`MATCH`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) to match for associated date within the sorted array. So for movie "A" with date "4-Jun-22" (= `44716`) we get `3`.
- `f_diff,IFERROR(INDEX(sorted,SEQUENCE(ROWS(sorted),,2))-sorted,0)`: here we calculate the forward looking difference between the elements in our sorted array. The part `INDEX(sorted,SEQUENCE(ROWS(sorted),,2))` shifts the sorted array one element forward (see [`INDEX`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) and [`SEQUENCE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90#:%7E:text=The%20SEQUENCE%20function%20allows%20you,365%20subscribers%20in%20Current%20Channel.)). I.e. for movie "A" we are saying here: get me the entire length of rows from the sorted array, but start at `2`: `INDEX({44713;44714;44716;44718;44719},{2;3;4;5;6})` -> `{44714;44716;44718;44719;#REF!}` (the `#REF!` error occurs because for the last element we are stepping out of bounds (i.e. the sorted array does not in fact have an element `6`). Now we subtract the original sorted array, and wrap this in `IFERROR(result,0)` to get a `0` for the last element. For movie "A" `{44714;44716;44718;44719;#REF!}-{44713;44714;44716;44718;44719}` results in `{1;2;2;1;0}`. All dates in our sorted array that are part of a consecutive date sequence (*except the last element of such a sequence*) will now have associated `1's`: true here for `44713` and `44718` ("1-Jun-22", "6-Jun-22").
- `sum_dupl,IFERROR(SUM(--(INDEX(f_diff,SEQUENCE(match_date-1))=1)),0)`: let's take `INDEX(f_diff,SEQUENCE(match_date-1))` first. Here we take our f_diff array and request only the part that *runs up to, but does not include* the position of our associated date. Recall that `match_date = 3` for movie "A" and date "4-Jun-22". So, we asking here to get back rows {1,2} from f_diff. This gets us back: `{1;2}`, meaning: 1st date is part of a consecutive date sequence (2nd date is too, but remember: it's the last element, so we don't need it). Next, `SUM(--({1;2}=1)` -> `SUM(--({TRUE;FALSE}))` -> `1` (on the double unary operator (`--`) see e.g. [here](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary#:%7E:text=A%20unary%20operation%20is%20an,formulas%20that%20work%20with%20arrays.)). What is this number telling us: movie "A" with date "4-Jun-22" is preceded by 1 element that is part of a consecutive date sequence, but not the last element (namely: "1-Jun-22"). Finally, we have to wrap the function in `IFERROR(result,0)` to fix the calculation error that will occur for the first date of each movie (here `match_date = 1`, leading to `SEQUENCE(1-1)`, which is impossible). We pick `0`, since the first date obviously cannot have prior consecutive date sequences.
- `match_date-sum_dupl`: final calculation. Here we simply take the regular rank (`match_date`) and subtract the number for the prior consecutive date sequences that we've just calculated (`sum_dupl`). So, `3-1` for movie "A" and date "4-Jun-22".

Let's just get some visual sense of this breakdown:

[image: desired result visual breakdown]

So, to take the highlighted example: movie "B" with date "7-Jun-22". The "Regular_Rank" would be `5`. `d_fill` gets us: `{1;1;3;1;0}`. We sum all `1's` in this array up to, but not including "7-Jun-22" itself, so `{1;1;3;1}` and get `3`. That is: "1/2/6-Jun-22" are all three part of consecutive date sequences ("3-Jun-22" is a last element, so not counted). "Desired_Rank" will equal `5-3`.

Hope that all makes sense. Let me know if you experience any difficulties with implementation.